# python how to check if a string is an element of a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

In python, how to check if a string is an element of a list of strings?

The example data I am working with is :

```
testData=pd.DataFrame({'value':['abc','cde','fgh']})
```

Then why the result of the following code is "False":

```
testData['value'][0] in testData['value']
```

Comment: Sorry the data will be stored as a Series containing individual strings in your sample df but is your real df data really a list of strings for each row? As that is fundamentally different

Comment: @EdChum answer is a good one. To help fix your original error, you simply need to check the values of testData['value'] so your last line will be 'testData['value'][0] in testData['value'].values' and you will get a True

Comment: @EdChum, I guess the example data is a more accurate description of my problem. The fundamental difference you mentioned might be the thing I overlooked.

Comment: actually `testData['value'][0] in testData['value']` I can't explain, somehow when the scalar value is the lhs it's somehow able to evaluate the `Series` array into a scalar boolean which is weird

Comment: I found the answer to your last question

Comment: @EdChum Whats the confusion. Changing `testData['value']` to `testData['value'].values` corrects the error

Comment: @A.Kot the confusion is why `testData['value'][0] in testData['value']` gives `False` not that `testData['value'][0] in testData['value'].values` works because that will use `np.array.__contains__` which does what you expect whilst for pandas `Series` you're checking for membership of the index, see the bottom of my answer

Comment: @EdChum Oh yeah makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the vectorised [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to test if a string is present/contained in each row :

```
In [262]:
testData['value'].str.contains(testData['value'][0])

Out[262]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

If you're after whether it's present in any row then use `any`:

```
In [264]:
testData['value'].str.contains(testData['value'][0]).any()

Out[264]:
True
```

OK to address your last question:

```
In [270]:
testData['value'][0] in testData['value']

Out[270]:
False
```

This is because `pd.Series.__contains__` is implemented:

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    """True if the key is in the info axis"""
    return key in self._info_axis
```

If we look at what `_info_axis` actually is:

```
In [269]:
testData['value']._info_axis

Out[269]:
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

Then we can see when we do `'abc'` in `testData['value']` we're really testing whether `'abc'` is actually in the index which is why it returns `False`

Example:

```
In [271]:
testData=pd.DataFrame({'value':['abc','cde','fgh']}, index=[0, 'turkey',2])
testData

Out[271]:
       value
0        abc
turkey   cde
2        fgh

In [272]:
'turkey' in testData['value']

Out[272]:
True
```

We can see that is returns `True` now because we're testing if 'turkey' is present in the index